# Apache Ignite Spring-Data (IgniteRepository), Apache Ignite Spring Cache (SpringCacheManager) with thin-client and thick-client

Tags: spring, spring-data, ignite, thin-client, thick-client

1. Is it possible to use a THIN-client with Ignite Spring-Data (IgniteRepository) and Ignite Spring Cache (SpringCacheManager) ?
2. Is it possible to use a THICK-client with Ignite Spring-Data (IgniteRepository) and Ignite Spring Cache (SpringCacheManager) ?

PS:

THIN-client - use interface IgniteClient,

THICK-client - igniteConfiguration.setClientMode(true)

Answer (score 2):

It works only with the thick client currently.

The documentation shows how to configure and use it: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/spring/spring-caching

Comment: IgniteRepository works with THICK-client ?

Answer (score 0):

It is expected in 2.11 version:

https://github.com/apache/ignite-extensions

https://github.com/apache/ignite-extensions/tree/master/modules/spring-cache-ext

https://github.com/apache/ignite-extensions/blob/master/modules/spring-cache-ext/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/cache/spring/IgniteClientSpringCacheManager.java

> There are two implementations of Apache Ignite Spring Cache Manager -
> org.apache.ignite.cache.spring.SpringCacheManager and
> org.apache.ignite.cache.spring.IgniteClientSpringCacheManager, that
> provide ability to use the Ignite thick or thin client to connect to
> the Ignite cluster and manage Ignite caches, respectively. Note, that
> org.apache.ignite.cache.spring.IgniteClientSpringCacheManager can be
> used only with Ignite since 2.11.0 version.